# Problem: failed to create task or type thrift because ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar is missing

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, ant

When I build my project on Eclipse with **Ant**, it works. But when I do it with **Jenkins**, I have this error :

```
Problem: failed to create task or type thrift
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I found out it must be because of an external jar: `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar`, that is missing. On Eclipse, I configured *window/preferences/ant/runtime* and added my external jar but I don't know how to do it with Jenkins.

Do you have any idea where on the configuration I could add this jar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jar can be located anywhere on the system; you just need to add a `taskdef` step to your build.xml that contains a `classpath` that points to it. See http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="/path/to/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

That said, ant-contrib does not contain a `thrift` task, to my knowledge. Here's a list of all the extra tasks ant-contrib adds: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html

Maybe you were looking for this? https://github.com/ehrmann/thrift-task